# Mongodb: Segmentation Fault

Tags: mongodb

This is the second time it happens and chash my app, i have no idea where it comes from, here is the last logs i get before the Segmentation Fault:

```
2014-05-22T04:24:22.547+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2014-05-22T04:29:22.567+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:107 virt:1479
2014-05-22T04:29:22.567+0200 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):1248
2014-05-22T04:29:22.567+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2014-05-22T04:34:22.598+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:107 virt:1479
2014-05-22T04:34:22.598+0200 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):1248
2014-05-22T04:34:22.598+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2014-05-22T04:39:22.618+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:108 virt:1479
2014-05-22T04:39:22.618+0200 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):1248
2014-05-22T04:39:22.618+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2014-05-22T04:44:22.637+0200 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:107 virt:1479
2014-05-22T04:44:22.637+0200 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):1248
2014-05-22T04:44:22.637+0200 [clientcursormon]  connections:10
2014-05-22T04:45:00.699+0200 [conn49] SEVERE: Invalid access at address: 0x2007dc60c2
2014-05-22T04:45:00.734+0200 [conn49] SEVERE: Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
Backtrace:0x11bd301 0x11bc6de 0x11bc7cf 0x326c9a82bb0 0x796892 0x796fbf 0x79773d 0x7979ff 0xc3d34a 0xc48ca6 0x9ffb41 0xa002d0 0xa01b5f 0xa030bd 0xa06dbe 0xa1cfda 0xa1e04e 0xa1f806 0xd4c6a7 0xb96382
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11bd301]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x11bc6de]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x11bc7cf]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbb0) [0x326c9a82bb0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11mutablebson8Document4Impl12writeElementINS_16BSONArrayBuilderEEEvjPT_PKNS_10StringDataE+0x52) [0x796892]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11mutablebson8Document4Impl13writeChildrenINS_16BSONArrayBuilderEEEvjPT_+0x4f) [0x796fbf]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11mutablebson8Document4Impl12writeElementINS_14BSONObjBuilderEEEvjPT_PKNS_10StringDataE+0x22d) [0x79773d]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11mutablebson8Document4Impl13writeChildrenINS_14BSONObjBuilderEEEvjPT_+0x4f) [0x7979ff]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugEPNS_12UpdateDriverEPNS_14CanonicalQueryE+0x115a) [0xc3d34a]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14UpdateExecutor7executeEv+0x66) [0xc48ca6]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x9ffb41]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor10execUpdateERKNS_12BatchItemRefEPNS_7BSONObjEPPNS_16WriteErrorDetailE+0x80) [0xa002d0]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor11bulkExecuteERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestEPSt6vectorIPNS_19BatchedUpsertDetailESaIS6_EEPS4_IPNS_16WriteErrorDetailESaISB_EE+0x1df) [0xa01b5f]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo18WriteBatchExecutor12executeBatchERKNS_21BatchedCommandRequestEPNS_22BatchedCommandResponseE+0x8cd) [0xa030bd]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8WriteCmd3runERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x3de) [0xa06dbe]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x3a) [0xa1cfda]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPS0_RNS_6ClientEiPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xd5e) [0xa1e04e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x6c6) [0xa1f806]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11newRunQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_+0x2307) [0xd4c6a7]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xb96382]
2014-05-22T11:55:32.419+0200 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-05-22T11:55:32.420+0200 WARNING: Cannot detect if NUMA interleaving is enabled. Failed to probe "/sys/devices/system/node/node1": Permission denied
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=28179 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=vps54740.ovh.net
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten]
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Cannot detect if NUMA interleaving is enabled. Failed to probe "/sys/devices/system/node/node1": Permission denied
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.0
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] git version: 1c1c76aeca21c5983dc178920f5052c298db616c
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build14.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-05-22T11:55:32.425+0200 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
...
```

What do you think can do that ?
I have a lot of free memory on my server and i didn't have any traffic when it happened.
Could it be an attack ?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug from the 2.6 version when updating arrays on documents with more than 128 BSON elements:

[Here is the issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13516?jql=project%20=%20SERVER%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%20%222.6.1%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22segmentation%20fault%22)

As they say, it's corrected since the 2.6.1 version, so i encourage you to upgrade as i did !